# plotAnimator pie don't do an animation

Tags: jquery, flot

I'm using the plugin `jquery.flot.animator.min.js` to animate a pie chart done with flot but I have an error

`TypeError: o[0] is undefined`

Is possible to use this plugin to animate a pie (I saw in the examples only lines, points and bars)?

This is a snap of code

```
<html>
    <head>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="static/js_fw/flot/0.8.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="static/js_fw/flot/0.8.1/jquery.flot.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="static/js_fw/flot/0.8.1/jquery.flot.animator.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">

    .demo-container {
        position: relative;
        height: 400px;
    }

    #placeholder {
        width: 550px;
        height: 400px;
    }



    </style>

    <script type="text/JavaScript">

    var pippo = function() {

        // Randomly Generated Data

        var data = [],
            series = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 3;

        for (var i = 0; i < series; i++) {
            data[i] = {
                label: "Series" + (i + 1),
                data: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1
            }
        }

        $.plotAnimator('#placeholder', data, {
            series: {
                pie: {
                    show: true,
                    radius: 3/4,
                    label: {
                        show: true,
                        radius: 3/4,
                        //formatter: labelFormatter,
                        background: {
                            opacity: 0.5,
                            color: '#000'
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            legend: {
                show: true
            }
        });

    };

    $(function() {
        pippo();
    });


    </script>
    <title>Radar Chart</title>
    </head>
    <body >

    <div class="demo-container">
            <div id="placeholder" class="demo-placeholder"></div>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The animator plug-in expects data in Flot's standard format, where each series has an array of [x, y] pairs.  The error comes when it tries to read the single pie value as an array.

But even if you worked around this, the animation is done by progressively adding points to a series; with a pie you only have one point, so it wouldn't do anything.

So no, the animate plugin doesn't support pies.